# Xen machine can see others on subnet but not gateway

Tags: linux, networking, xen, ping, gateway

EDIT: solved

it appears that switching static MAC definitions combined with mapping vif/0 and vif/0 statically to eth0 and eth1 (in domU, as per http://tomclegg.net/xen-eth0-renamed) done it.

I'm troubleshooting this strange issue (well, for me at least) on my xen domU.

Here's the basic layout:

```
-------- -------------
|      | | XEN  d0   |
|  A   | | --------- |
|      | | | xen dU| |
-------- -------------
```

Host A is unrelated machine with IP 213.226.13x.yyy/24

XEN d0 is the hypervisor with IP 213.226.13x.zzz/24

XEN dU is the guest OS (debian etch) I'm trying to configure to see the gateway, it has IP 213.226.13x.jjj/24

The gateway is 213.226.13x.1.

All machines are on the same subnet. The problem is that gues OS can't ping the gateway, but can ping dom0 and host A no problem.

dom0 and host A can ping each other, the gateway and guest.

Things I've tried on host A:

ARP ping

$ arping -c 1 -i eth0 213.226.13x.1

```
ARPING 213.226.13x.1
60 bytes from 00:02:b3:e8:30:7e (213.226.13x.1): index=0 time=224.113 usec
...
```

(strangely, arping -c 1 -i eth0 00:02:b3:e8:30:7e does not work).

Broadcast ping

$ ping -b 213.226.13x.255

```
WARNING: pinging broadcast address
PING 213.226.13x.255 (213.226.13x.255) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 213.226.13x.18: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.463 ms
64 bytes from 213.226.13x.28: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.478 ms (DUP!)
...
```

Same stuff on xen guest doesn't return any results (both, arping and ping -b).

$ iptables -L output on both, host A and xen guest is the same (zero rules):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Things I've ruled out as of this time:

damaged physical link - XEN dom0 wouldn't work also, which is not the case.

firewall on gateway - my ARP pings would still get through?

firewall on xen guest - iptables -L has no rules

routing issue - not sure about this one, but I wouldn't be able to ping host A and dom0 with messed up routing table, would I?

Any help is very much appreciated

EDIT1: additional info

I'm not using xen's bridging scripts, network-dummy instead with manually created br-eth1 for eth1 which is the interface for the local network. eth0 is the bridge created by XEN installation for eth0 interface (renamed to peth0 AFAIK).

Here's how /etc/network/interfaces look like on dom0:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 213.226.13x.zzz
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 213.226.13x.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

auto br-eth1
iface br-eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.1.11
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

And "brctl show" (with domU being off)..

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br-eth1     8000.000423d0d059   no      eth1
eth0        8000.000423d0d058   no      peth0
```

EDIT2: additional info

XEN config for domU:

```
#
#  Bootloader + kernel + memory size
#
bootloader  = '/usr/lib/xen-3.2-1/bin/pygrub'
kernel      = '/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-5-xen-686'
ramdisk     = '/boot/initrd.img-2.6.18-5-xen-686'
memory      = '3072'
vcpus       = '4'

#
#  Disk device(s).
#
root        = '/dev/sda1 ro'
disk        = [
                  'phy:/dev/vg_main/domain-disk,sda1,w',
                  'phy:/dev/vg_main/domain-swap,sda2,w',
              ]


#
#  Hostname
#
name        = '...'

#
#  Networking
#
vif = [
        'ip=213.226.13x.jjj,mac=00:16:3E:83:0B:BC,bridge=eth0',
        'ip=192.168.1.12,mac=00:16:3E:83:0B:AC,bridge=br-eth1',
]

#
#  Behaviour
#
on_poweroff = 'destroy'
on_reboot   = 'restart'
on_crash    = 'restart'
```

Comment: Need all networking details, along with tcpdumps for all cases at all points in the chain.

Comment: If you could provide the output from running `/sbin/ip addr`, `/sbin/ip route` and `/usr/sbin/brctl show` that would help

Comment: It would be clearer to place your solution as an answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. Show your xen bridge/route script (that actually provides network for domU).
2. What's the difference in tcpdump output on dom0 external interface when you ping host A and gateway from domU ?