# Xen: network between dom0 and domU does not working, while network between particular domUs does

Tags: networking, xen, bridge

I am unable to establish communication between domU and dom0. I have two domUs and they are able communicate between each other. Dom0 is connected to Internet. I just need network between dom0 and domUs, domUs does not need to have Internet access but should be able to communicate between each other as it is now. I want to keep setting on dom0 as minimal as it is possible and do not want to play with IP addressing etc (it is a remote machine and I do not wat to cut my connection). So far I've tried this:

1. set up bridge br0 on dom0
2. started two VMs (they use br0 as a bridge)
3. set up ip addressing for VMs: 192.168.1.1/24 and 192.168.1.2/24
4. flushed the firewall on dom0

PROBLEM: domUs are able to communicate with each other but dom0 with domUs are unable to communicate. The things I've tried so far:

1. assign an IP for bridge br0 192.168.1.3 and ping that IP from domU - did not work (even if the bridge does not have IP address the domUs are able to communicate).
2. create dummy interface assign an IP 192.168.1.4 and add it to br0 and ping it from domU - did not work. But domUs communication is still working

PS: I have found several similar questions/answers but none seems a right answer:

1. [network-bridge-in-dom0-can-not-ping-domus](https://serverfault.com/questions/444645/network-bridge-in-dom0-can-not-ping-domus)
2. [xen-cant-get-dom0-and-the-domus-to-ping-eachother](https://serverfault.com/questions/457143/xen-cant-get-dom0-and-the-domus-to-ping-eachother)
3. [xen-machine-can-see-others-on-subnet-but-not-gateway](https://serverfault.com/questions/37449/xen-machine-can-see-others-on-subnet-but-not-gateway)

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you're communicating with the right IPs of dom0 (vifX.Y interface)? What IPs are all devices? Is there any kind of firewalling set up?

Comment: Seems that it is working now. The actual config is with bridge which has the IP from same subnet as guest VMs. So no dummy interface is created. I will try to add dummy to this bridge if it will break connection.

Comment: Flush firewall? Better disable it completely on the Dom0.